# House of Israel Vs House of Judah

Tags: yirmiyahu--book-of, yehuda, israel

In the book of the prophet Yirmiyahu - he refers to both the house of Israel and the house of Judah. However, Israel (the Northern Kingdom) had been destroyed for over ~100 years. Take chapter 5 vs 11 for instance, For the house of Israel and the house of Judah have dealt very treacherously with Me,” says the Lord.

Then in a couple verses down, it says the following: Behold, I will bring a nation against you from afar,
O house of Israel,” says the Lord.
“It is a mighty nation,
It is an ancient nation,
A nation whose language you do not know,
Nor can you understand what they say.

So we can see, within the same chapter, Yirmiyahu makes a distinction between both houses; however, in a few verses down, he speaks as if the house of Israel had not been destroyed yet. Why does Yirmiyahu speak as if Israel had not yet fallen? What am I not understanding? He clearly uses 'house of Israel' and 'house of Judah' to make distinctions between the 2 in vs 5, but then acts as if, at the time of his writing, Israel had not yet been destroyed.

Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: וְגַ֛ם בַּיָּמִ֥ים הָהֵ֖מָּה נְאֻם־יְהֹוָ֑ה לֹא־אֶעֱשֶׂ֥ה אִתְּכֶ֖ם כָּלָֽה׃ 
Nevertheless in those days, says the Lord, I will not make a full end with you.

Comment: it is more so the concept of Northern Israel wanting to have departed from Davidic dynasty (symbolized in Judah), even those that are removed from Torah and Mitzvot (not entirely though) can be restored and come back and join the branch of Judah (the faithful branch). And even when Judah is not so faithful, as rosends mentioned, God will not make a full end with them. That’s why Jeremiah 31 speaks of reestablishing the Law (Torah and mitzvot) in their hearts. Hope this clarifies a bit